# Why $A(x)u=c\implies A(x)=[\partial _{u_j}F_i(x,u)]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F:\mathbb R^{N+M}\to \mathbb R^M$ a function. We want to find $u\in \mathbb R^M$ s.t. $$F(x,u)=0,$$
and $u$ of the form $u=f(x)=(f_1(x),...,f_M(x)),$ with $x=(x_1,...,x_N)\in\mathbb R^N$. We suppose that $F_i$ are of the form
$$F_i(x_1,...,x_N,u_1,...,u_M)=\sum_{j=1}^M a_{ij}(x)u_j-c_i,\quad 1\leq i\leq M,$$
sot that $$F(x,u)=A(x)u-c,\quad A(x)=[a_{ij}(x)],\quad c=(c_1,...,c_M).$$
We therefore have to sole $$A(x)u=c.\tag{E}$$

In my book i's written that "it's well know that if $\det A(x)\neq 0$, then the solution of $(E)$ is given by $$u=[A(x)]^{-1}c,$$
where $$A(x)=[\partial _{u_j}F_i(x,u)].$$

**Question :** I really don't see why $A(x)=[\partial _{u_j}F_i(x,u)]$. How do we prove it ?

Comment: If $F_j$ takes the form above, then $\partial_{u_j} F_i = \partial_{u_j} (\sum_{k=1}^m a_{i,k} (x)u_i - c_i) = a_{i,j}(x)$. Seems about right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your definition $$F_i(x_1,\cdots,x_N,u_1,\cdots, u_M) = \sum_{j=1}^M a_{ij}(x)u_j-c_i\tag 1 \\ A(x) = a_{ij}(x)$$ now if you take the partial derivative of $(1)$ with respect to $u_j$ what you get is exactly $a_{ij}(x)$ which from your definition is the matrix $A$.

Let me make it more clear. The function $F$ is defined as a vector $F=(F_1\cdots F_M)^T$ which from the definition $(1)$ is $$F = \left(\begin{matrix}\sum_{j=1}^M a_{1j}(x)u_j-c1\\\sum_{j=1}^M a_{2j}(x)u_j-c2\\\vdots\\\sum_{j=1}^M a_{Mj}(x)u_j-c_M\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}(x)u_1+\cdots+a_{1M}(x)u_M-c_1\\a_{21}(x)u_1+\cdots+a_{2M}(x)u_M-c_2\\\vdots\\a_{M1}(x)u_1+\cdots+a_{MM}(x)u_M-c_M\end{matrix}\right)= \\=\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}(x)u_1+\cdots+a_{1M}(x)u_M\\a_{21}(x)u_1+\cdots+a_{2M}(x)u_M\\\vdots\\a_{M1}(x)u_1+\cdots+a_{MM}(x)u_M\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}c_1\\c_2\\\vdots\\c_M\end{matrix}\right) = \\ = \left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}(x)&\cdots &a_{1M}(x)\\a_{21}(x) &\cdots &a_{2M}(x)\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{M1}(x) &\cdots &a_{MM}(x)\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_M\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}c_1\\c_2\\\vdots\\c_M\end{matrix}\right) = \\ = A(x)u-c$$ Now if we differentiate the $i$-th element of $F$ with respect to the $j$-th element of $u$ we get $$F_i(x) = a_{i1}(x)u_1+\cdots +a_{ij}(x)u_j+\cdots+a_{iM}(x)u_M-c_M\\ \partial_{u_j}F_i = 0+\cdots+a_{ij}(x)+\cdots+0-0= a_{ij}$$ all the zeros ar there because with respect to $u_j$ all the others $u_i$ with $i\neq j$ are just constants as is $c_i$. From the last equality follows that $$A(x) = a_{ij}(x) = \partial_{u_j}F_i$$